# Cleanest way to add no styling <768px

Tags: css

I currently use the code below over 768px, but wish to have no styling when it goes to mobile. I have tried adding 0 for the values and none, but nothing seems to happen.

```
.mybox {
    padding: 20px !important;
    border: 1px solid #fff !important;
    height: 250px;
}
```

This is what I tried below

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .mybox {
         padding: none;
         border: none;
         height: none;
     }
}
```

Is there a way to set no styling at all, in the cleanest fashion?

Comment: Try to avoid using `!important` instead try to rely on [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it the other way around, with min-width:

```
@media all and (min-width: 769px) {
  .mybox {
  padding: 20px !important;
  border: 1px solid #fff !important;
  height: 250px;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can leave the `all and` part off from the code, just present the min-width and its value.